# Powershell - Trouble With Loops

Tags: powershell

First I would like to generate a directory listing for all text files in a directory. Next take each of those text files and get-contents. Then I want to go through the contents and search for all text files in another directory which share contents with the first file and output those corresponding matches to a file named after the source file.

I'm very new at all of this and realize I'm missing some serious fundamental chunks of knowledge. What little scripting experience I have is in Javascript which doesn't seem entirely transferable. (Although programming is programming I'm told.)

This is what I have so far:

```
$max = get-content h:test1\one.txt | Measure-Object
$A = get-content h:test1\one.txt
For($i=0; $i -lt $max.count ; $i++){
    select-string h:test2\*.txt -pattern $($A[$i]) | Format-Table | Out-File ($i + '.txt')
    }
```

I'm hoping for something like:

```
$max = get-content $files[i] | Measure-Object
    $A = get-content files[i]
    For($j=0; $j -lt $max.count ; $j++){
        select-string h:test2\*.txt -pattern $($A[$j]) | Format-Table | Out-File($files[i].basename + $j + '.txt')
    }
```

Any and all help would be extremely appreciated,

Kurtis

So

Book 1 (one.txt)

The capital of France is Paris.
The population of Paris is twelve.

Book 2 (two.txt)

France is a beautiful country.
The capital of France is Paris.

I basically want a report of the fact that two.txt shares a line with one.txt.

Comment: when you say share contents, do you mean identical files? Or simply that they have some portion of their contents in common?

Comment: That some portion of their contents are in common.

Comment: So full line matches would be sufficient?

Comment: Full lines works. Haha in an ideal world it would actually be sentences but I somehow think that would complicate :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK let's break this down:

> First I would like to generate a directory listing for all text files in a directory. Next take each of those text files and get-contents.

```
dir *.txt | get-content
```

> Then I want to go through the contents and search for all text files
>   in another directory which share contents with the first file

OK, now we pipe all that text to `select-string` (first filtering out all empty string with `?{$_}`:

```
dir *.txt | get-content | ?{$_} | %{select-string -path searchPath\*.txt -pattern "$_" -simple}
```

> and output those corresponding matches to a file named after the
>   source file.

So now it gets tricky because we have to go back and track our source file name, we do this by wraqpping our query in a foreach (i.e. `%{}` ):

```
dir *.txt | %{ $sourceFile = $_; get-content $_ | ?{$_} | %{select-string -path searchPath\*.txt -pattern "$_" -simple} | out-file "$sourceFile.results" }
```

Answer (score 5):

> First I would like to generate a directory listing for all text files in a directory

Here's how:

```
$textFiles1 = dir -Path C:\Books1 -Filter *.txt
$textFiles2 = dir -Path C:\Books2 -Filter *.txt
```

> 1. Next take each of those text files and get-contents.
> 2. I want to see whether any lines from the first book are in any of the other books.

Here's an algorithm to do this <strike>(untested)</strike> (tested):

```
foreach ($textFile in $textFiles1) {
    $lines = get-content -Path $textFile
    foreach ($line in $lines) {
        foreach ($textFile2 in $textFiles2) {
            $lines2 = get-content -Path $textFile2 
            if ($lines2 -contains $line) {
                $matchMessage = 'Line: "{0}" is duplicated in "{1}".' -f $line, $textFile2
                $matchMessage | out-file C:\report.txt -encoding UTF8 -Append
            }
        }
    } 
}

notepad C:\report.txt
```

Comment: Clarified at the bottom of original question. Haha I haevn't gotten the hang of this interface yet sorry :P

Comment: @KurtisStaples-King I updated my answer. Give that a try... You'll have to fix the paths to what you want of course...

Comment: Love it! I'd Vote Up but I have a seedy reputation :P

Comment: @KurtisStaples-King Fixed the issue with piping to Get-Content. It works now :-)